# JSF - Table updated through jquery not reflecting on page submit on server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I have created a table in JSF through ui:repeat tag. And I'm trying to add/remove rows on the client side through jquery. Which works fine by showing a newly added row or by removing the particular row on the front end.

However, when I submit the form to see if the new rows are reflecting on the server side, the arraylist doesn't seem to reflect the latest rows that is displayed on the browser, but it has only the initial list that was present before the updates.

I'm new to JSF and after lot of searching I'm not able to find how to make the new row updates to reflect on the server side arraylist from which the table was created in the first place.

Could anyone tell me if this is possible and if so how it can be done?

Thanks in Advance.

Please find my code below:

## JSF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.0.js" target="body" />
<h:outputScript target="body">
function my_new_js_function()
{
  $('tr').click(function(){
            var currentRow = $(this);
            currentRow.remove();
    });
  
  return false;
}

function appendNewDummyRow()
{
$('#myTable').append('<tr id="myRow"><td id="myCell"><input id="myForm:myObjectId:5:empName" type="text" name="myForm:myObjectId:5:empName" value="New Name" size="10" /></td><td><input id="myForm:myObjectId:5:empDepartment" type="text" name="myForm:myObjectId:5:empDepartment" value="New Customer Care" size="20" /></td><td><input id="myForm:myObjectId:5:empAge" type="text" name="myForm:myObjectId:5:empAge" value="0" size="5" /></td><td><input id="myForm:myObjectId:5:empSalary" type="text" name="myForm:myObjectId:5:empSalary" value="0" size="5" /></td><td><a class="deleteLink" onclick="my_new_js_function();return false;">delete</a></td></tr>');

//alert(document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML);

$('#myTable').html(document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML);

return false;
}

</h:outputScript>

<h:head>
    <title>JSF Sample</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="msgid"></div>
    <h2>DataTable Example</h2>
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <table id="myTable" border="1" styleClass="employeeTable">
            <ui:repeat id="myObjectId" var="employee" value="#{userData.employees}">
                <tr id="myRow">
                    <td id="myCell"><h:inputText id="empName" value="#{employee.name}" size="10" /></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="empDepartment" value="#{employee.department}" size="20" />
                    </td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="empAge" value="#{employee.age}" size="5" /></td>
                    <td><h:inputText id="empSalary" value="#{employee.salary}" size="5" /></td>
                    <td><a class="deleteLink"
                        onclick="my_new_js_function();return false;" href="">delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </ui:repeat>
        </table>
        <h:commandButton value="Check Result" action="#{userData.checkResult}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form @this"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandButton>
        <a  onclick="appendNewDummyRow();return false;" href="">addDummyRow</a>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

## UserBean.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "userData")
@SessionScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable {

    public UserData()
    {
    if(employees == null)
        employees  = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
    }
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private String name;
   private String department;
   private int age;
   private double salary;
   
   private ArrayList<Employee> employees
      = new ArrayList<Employee>(Arrays.asList(
      new Employee("John", "Marketing", 30,2000.00),
      new Employee("Robert", "Marketing", 35,3000.00),
      new Employee("Mark", "Sales", 25,2500.00),
      new Employee("Chris", "Marketing", 33,2500.00),
      new Employee("Peter", "Customer Care", 20,1500.00)
   ));  
   
    public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees() {
      return employees;
   }

   public void setEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
          this.employees = employees;
   }
   
   public String addEmployee() {         
      Employee employee = new Employee(name,department,age,salary);
      employees.add(employee);
      return null;
   }

   public String deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
      employees.remove(employee);       
      return null;
   }

   public void checkResult() {
       System.out.println("printing new size of the list = "+ employees.size());
       
       for (Employee employee : employees){
             System.out.println("Value given from input text = "+ employee.getName());
          }
       
       }
   
   public String editEmployee(Employee employee){
      employee.setCanEdit(true);
      return null;
   }

   public String saveEmployees(){
      //set "canEdit" of all employees to false 
      for (Employee employee : employees){
         employee.setCanEdit(false);
      }     
      return null;
   }
   
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getDepartment() {
      return department;
   }

   public void setDepartment(String department) {
      this.department = department;
   }

   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
   }

   public double getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }

   public void setSalary(double salary) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate the JSF state like that.

You have to add new rows from server side, and render them by updating the ui:repeat.

Instead of the `<a onclick="appendNewDummyRow();return false;" href="">addDummyRow</a>` you should create a button (or a command link) as

```
<p:commandButton value="addDummyRow" process="@this" update="myObjectId" action="#{userData.addEmployee}" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushee for your comments. But in our project, our boss wants us to try out the client side table manipulation through addition or deletion of rows and then finally send the new list to the server side on Form submit. He says we shouldn't have to make unnecessary trips to server side for normal client side data manipulation. So I'm trying to work out this way. So isn't there any way to have the state reflected in server side when it has been manipulated on the client side through Jquery or javascript?

Comment: I'm also interested to know if there is any other way that this can be done where the trips to server side can be avoided for adding or removing a row to the table and finally the list can be sent to the server side. Please let me konw. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want too much ajax requests, you should seek for another framefork instead of using JSF. The main point of the JSF is that you store your state in server side, so unfortunately... No, you can't do this with JSF.